# How to model a box with a circular top?

Tags: modeling

[image: a diagram]

I would like to create a cube with slightly rounded edges (less round than in the diagram above though) that morphs into a flat, cylindrical front with a gentle curve towards one end. (The diagram is not to scale at all.)

Comment: The bevel modifier will help you out: https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/generate/bevel.html#bevel-modifier

Answer (score 9):

Start with a box and subdivide (<kbd>W</kbd> > *Subdivide*) it to give yourself more geometry to work with.  Then select the corner edges of the side you want to make circular and hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> (scale to sphere) and type `1` (to make it scale it 100% to a sphere).  You will then have to scale it in a little (with <kbd>S</kbd>) to whatever size you want.  Repeat the process with the lower edge loops and <100% amounts to get a nice smooth interpolation (do it more than I did in the below GIF to get a higher resolution curve).

[image]

---

To get the rounded edges you can use a *Bevel* modifier with the limit method set to *Angle*.  Play with the threshold angle and bevel amount to get the desired look you want.

Comment: Thanks, and how do I tidy up n-gons?

Comment: @Cyrinadia  This process shouldn't create any n-gons.  What do you mean?